# What is the correct way of retrieving ParseUser using include.()

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm fairly new to Parse and I have 2 classes. The User class and another class that I called "Group". The Group class has a field called "users" where I keep ParseUser objects.

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Group");
    query.include("users");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, ""+parseObjects);
        }
    });
```

The `parseObjects` returned null, and I'm not sure where I went wrong. Any help?

Comment: Can't you query the User class instead? If not, I don't understand what you mean when you said that you have a field called users

Comment: The Group class has a relation with User class. The field (or column)  in the Group class points to User objects, which I'm trying to retrieve with this query.

Comment: I believe any references made to ParseUsers in the database should be called like "_User"

Comment: look at how built in 'roles' works then grab that for your user groups : http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Role.html